# How to debug external code with IIS (not IIS Express)

Tags: c#, debugging, iis, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I have a number of IIS 8.5 sites in development, that all need to run simultaneously in my development environment, to simulate a distributed system.

These sites use various NuGet packages, with PDB files available, that I want to step into for debugging.  In particular I'm using some of the Microsoft Katana libraries and have downloaded the source code, matching the NuGet packages.

**My problem:**

When using IIS Express, I can open the Katana source code I want to debug in Visual Studio 2013 (eg OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.cs), set a breakpoint, then when running the site, the breakpoint will be hit.

But when I switch to using IIS (in the Visual Studio properties pages), the same breakpoint is just ignored.

*I've only used Katana as an example.* The general problem seems to be that when using IIS only C# source-code in the Visual Studio solution is debugged, but when IIS Express is being used, any matching source-code you have, can be debugged.

Is it possible to make IIS debug these external files in the same way that IIS Express does?

Visual Studio is running as administrator.

Comment: "in my development environment" - does that mean your IIS install is local to your machine, or do you need to attach a debugger to a remote machine?

Comment: Look at these links: [Enable Debugging on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525253%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [How to debug while running a test on IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172.aspx)

Comment: @StevenV My development environment is Windows 8.1 on my local machine (well, a Hyper-V instance of Windows 8.1 to be precise). Within that I'm running IIS and the various components of the distributed system I'm trying to debug.

Comment: @FoggyDay Thanks for the links, but I don't have a problem debugging my own source-code when using IIS, it is just external code.

Comment: Important Q #1: Do you need "remote debugging", or is your IIS "local"?  A: "Local". MSVS and IIS co-located on same Win 8.1 VM.  Q #2: is debugging enabled on IIS? A: Apparently, "Yes".  Q #3: Do you have source, or at least debug binaries (.pdb/symbols) for the "third party components" you wish to debug?

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes, using the Katana example, for the handler I want to debug I have the assembly's PDB file (which I can see is loaded in the modules window) and also the corresponding Katana source code, with the handler I want to debug open in Visual Studio. Breakpoints in this handler are hit fine in IIS Express but when I switch to use IIS they are not.